# Extracting amount of connected devices from a router

Tags: connection, router

I'm looking for a way to extract information from a router, be it from the router directly, through command, or through the routers webpage. I need to extract the amount of connected devices in real time. This has to be sent somewhere, where it gets processed and can be fed into an arduino.

The project is a kind of installation where light reacts to the amount of connected devices to the network. So more devices connected make the light do something and less make it do something else.

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Usually this information could be obtained from router's administration web interface.

For example, I found screenshot of Cisco router web interface:
[image]

Look at the bottom of the image: where are a "Current clients" field with number of clients.

So, this page could be loaded programmatically and parsed for the needed value.

As you didn't specified your router model, or your programming language or any other details, I can't give your more specific solution.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply already! At the moment i'm using a TP-link Router so i'll have to check if it has the same information. For programming language, either javascript or python but i don't know if this is possible with either of them.

Comment: Browse admin panel of your router and look for connected clients number. It should be where. With Python you can make HTTP request to your router (with login and password provided) and get the page, that contain needed information.

Answer (score 0):

My python isn't that good though. Is there anyway you can point me in the right direction as where to look for this. And the information is in another submenu so is this still possible?[this is what my router interface looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/il9rb.png)